# OperationalError: unable to open database file

Tags: python, django, sqlite, graphite

Graphite throwing the **unable to open database file**

```
tail -f /etc/httpd/logs/error_log
```

This is the setting.py file configuration

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'NAME': '/opt/graphite/webapp/test.db',
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': ''
  }
}
```

done

```
python manage.py  syncdb
```

The file exists in the below location

```
[root@bash  graphite]# ls -l /opt/graphite/webapp/test.db
-rw-rw-rw- 1 nobody nobody 65536 Nov 11 22:22 /opt/graphite/webapp/test.db
```

it throws below error

```
[Tue Nov 11 22:24:15 2014] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
[Tue Nov 11 22:24:15 2014] [error]     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
[Tue Nov 11 22:24:15 2014] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 452, in execute
[Tue Nov 11 22:24:15 2014] [error]     return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
[Tue Nov 11 22:24:15 2014] [error] OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check rights of user, from whom you are executing `python manage.py syncdb`.

This user must have rights to read and write for file `/opt/graphite/webapp/test.db`

And also to read, write and execute rights for folder `/opt/graphite/webapp/`

Try this commands (execute from the user, that starts `python manage.py syncdb`, probably it is current user)

```
sudo chown `whoami`:`whoami` /opt/graphite/webapp/test.db  # change owner
sudo chmod o+rw /opt/graphite/webapp/test.db  # add rights

sudo chown `whoami`:`whoami` /opt/graphite/webapp/
sudo chmod o+rwx /opt/graphite/webapp/
```